# T-SQL CTE Error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I get the following error when I try to execute a particular recursive CTE:

```
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "data_list" of recursive query "CTE".
```

This is nonsense. Each field is explicitly cast to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. 
Please help me. I've read many answers to this problem, here and elsewhere, all of which advise explicitly casting the column in question. I'm already doing this, and still get the error.

This code will reproduce the error:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tOwner') IS NOT NULL drop table #tOwner;
CREATE TABLE #tOwner(id int identity(1,1), email varchar(max) );
insert into #towner values ( cast('123@123.321'  as varchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('tsql rage'    as varchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('another@e.c'  as varchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('einstein.x.m' as varchar(max)));

;WITH data AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(max), email) datapoint FROM #tOwner 
), CTE ( data_list, datapoint, length ) AS ( 
        SELECT convert(VARCHAR(max),            ''           ),convert(VARCHAR(max),    ''     ),       0
    UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(VARCHAR(max),d.datapoint+';'+data_list),convert(VARCHAR(max),d.datapoint), length + 1
        FROM CTE c CROSS JOIN data d WHERE d.datapoint > c.datapoint 
)
SELECT D.data_list
FROM ( 
    SELECT data_list, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY length DESC ) 
    FROM CTE 
) D ( data_list, rank )
WHERE rank = 1 ;

drop table #tOwner;
```

If you find it relevant, `SELECT left(@@VERSION, 70)` returns:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (X64)   May 26 2009 14:13:01
```

Comment: The query works for me on SS05 (X86 though).  And, it works on my SS08 too.  Sorry, not much help there, except you have a good query for other versions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in SS08 SP1 x86.

Comment: This totally doesn't work on my SQL Server 2008  R2 Developer x64 instance.  Interesting problem.  It's starting to smell to me like a bug.  I mean, you have really done a good job at boiling this down.

Comment: It _didn't_ work for me, and then it did - after a few minutes of fiddling I ran the query again (replaced the # table with a physical table - then it worked).  Then reverted back to the code above and _that_ worked.  Looks like a _very weird bug_.

Comment: When I take the CROSS JOIN out and remove the references to C, it works, for what that's worth (not much).

Comment: Aha - if I run this in one particular database on my PC I get the error - if I run it vs. master, I don't.  A clue!  Does the collation of your tempdb match the collation of the database in which you're running the query?

Comment: @Will - Bingo I can produce and fix this at will by changing collations

Comment: @WillA dude thank you for this comment which led to the resolution of a multiple hour frustrating bug hunt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Will A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383167/will-a)'s comment on my original post found the key - the collation. My posted query worked for me in the master database, too.

Examining the collation suggested I was on the right track.

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('crm_mscrm', 'Collation') crmSQLCollation
crmSQLCollation
--------------------
Latin1_General_CI_AI
(1 row(s) affected)

SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Collation') masterSQLCollation
masterSQLCollation
----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Some frenzied searching later, I had this monstrosity of code, which

1. explicitly specifies collation on each column,
2. successfully executes, and
3. returns the expected results

To wit:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tOwner') IS NOT NULL drop table #tOwner;
CREATE TABLE #tOwner(id int identity(1,1), email nvarchar(max) );
insert into #towner values ( cast('123@123.321'  as nvarchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('tsql rage'    as nvarchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('another@e.c'  as nvarchar(max)));
insert into #towner values ( cast('einstein.x.m' as nvarchar(max)));

;WITH data AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT convert(nvarchar(max), email) datapoint FROM #tOwner 
), CTE ( data_list, datapoint, length ) AS ( 
        SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),            ''           ) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,convert(nvarchar(max),    ''     ) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,       0
    UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),d.datapoint+';'+data_list) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,convert(nvarchar(max),d.datapoint) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, length + 1
        FROM CTE c CROSS JOIN data d WHERE d.datapoint > c.datapoint 
)
SELECT D.data_list
FROM ( 
    SELECT data_list, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY length DESC ) 
    FROM CTE 
) D ( data_list, rank )
WHERE rank = 1 ;

if object_id('tempdb..#tOwner') IS NOT NULL drop table #tOwner;
```

Sitting beautifully in my results window is the expected:

```
data_list
------------------------------------------------
tsql rage;einstein.x.m;another@e.c;123@123.321;
```

Comment: For the record, this should at least be posted as a MS Connect issue.  They should at least give you a better error message.  This is pretty darned opaque to me.  Toughest SQL Server question I've ever seen on SO!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! :D I had the exact same error, with the added data type mismatch as well (took me a while to figure out I had both problems at once), but without the collation help, I'd probably have taken me days to figure out what was wrong (part of a big and complex query / db structure). Thank you both (@WillA) again! :)

Comment: Specifying the collation on the anchor worked for me as well.

Comment: THANK YOU. Been bashing my head on this for ages.