# SQL Server query CTE parent child, works in 2012 local but not in 2012 live, types don't match

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, common-table-expression

This query works in one server version but not in another.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EventDetails]
    @EventID AS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH CTE(CategoryID, FullCategName, OrderString) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CategoryID, 
            CAST(CategoryName AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
            CAST(CAST(CategoryID AS CHAR(5)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) OrderString
        FROM 
            CategoryTbl 
        WHERE 
            ParentCategoryIDf is NULL 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            p.CategoryID, 
            CAST(c.FullCategName + ' >> ' + p.CategoryName AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
            CAST(c.OrderString + CAST(p.CategoryID AS CHAR(5)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) OrderString
        FROM 
            CategoryTbl p
        JOIN
            CTE c ON c.CategoryID = p.ParentCategoryIDf
    )
    SELECT
        (SELECT TOP 1 i.ImageUrl 
         FROM ImageTbl i 
         WHERE i.ProductIDf = p.EventID) AS ImageURL, *   
    FROM
        EventTbl p
    LEFT JOIN
        CTE c on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryIDf
    WHERE
        p.EventID = @EventID        
END
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: so... I have to ask... what's in the `monsters_db`?  ... It's monsters, isn't it?

Comment: note that your local express instance is SQL Server 2014 per the version number on there.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a collation issue, try this:

```
WITH CTE(CategoryID, FullCategName, OrderString) AS (
  SELECT 
      CategoryID
    , cast(CategoryName as varchar(max)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as FullCategName 
    , cast(cast(CategoryID as char(5)) as varchar(max)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as OrderString
  FROM CategoryTbl 
  WHERE ParentCategoryIDf is NULL 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      p.CategoryID
    , cast(c.FullCategName + ' >> ' + p.CategoryName as varchar(max)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    , cast(c.OrderString + cast(p.CategoryID as char(5)) as varchar(max)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS --OrderString
  FROM CategoryTbl p
    JOIN CTE c 
      ON c.CategoryID = p.ParentCategoryIDf
)

select  
  (select top 1 i.ImageUrl 
   from ImageTbl i 
   where i.ProductIDf=p.EventID) as ImageURL
  , *  
  from EventTbl p
    left join CTE c on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryIDf
    where p.EventID=@EventID
end
```

Reference:

- [T-SQL CTE Error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3428115/2333499)

Comment: Thanks for the support